# Myanmar Datum 2000 information

Tags: coordinate-system, datum, myanmar

Does anybody know where I can find the technical details for Burma's latest datum? It's called Myanmar Datum 2000 and I can't find any details online. I need the details to create a custom datum on my Garmin GPS.

What I need is the dx, dy, dz, da, and df.

If this isn't available, what is the closest datum that could be used instead?

Comment: Perhaps you could contact suntac technologies (http://www.suntactechnologies.com/f.htm) who seem to have used it

Comment: I managed to track down the [Survey Dept](http://www.moecaf.gov.mm/userpage2.aspx?mid=24) website, but it had no information. It did say that you have to have military approval to buy topo maps...that implies to me that this type of info is not going to be available.

Comment: I Have a complete set of these maps, and now face the same question.

Answer (score 1):

We have set our Garmins to the Indian Thailand 1975 datum with Everest 1830 spheroid.  Seems to match.  Otherwise running WGS 84 gives us grids that are 3-5KM shy of true location.

Comment: I've used that in the past, but using it with the Myanmar maps still gives about a 200-500 meter error, which is not acceptable for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Myanmar Datum 2000
Everest 1830
a = 6377276.345
f = 0.00332445
1/f = 300.8017

Xshift -246.632
Yshift -784.833
Zshift -276.923

Comment: Reference: http://www.un-ggim-ap.org/uebm/201607/W020161026570135032964.pdf

Comment: The link to the reference provided above is dead. This is a current link: http://en.nasg.gov.cn/events/201612/W020161222343354164551.pdf. This is ostensibly official Myanmar government data, however, the flattening factor for the Everest 1830 ellipsoid appears to be incorrect. The parameters provided by George Nyi above are evidently the correct ones and coincide with the 1937 definition of the Everest 1830 ellipsoid. His dx, dy, and dz values are the same as in the reference.

Comment: It should be worth clarifying the given shifts are WG84 to local.

Answer (score 0):

**proj4:**
`+proj=longlat +a=6377276.345 +rf=300.8017 +towgs84=246.632,784.833,276.923,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

Since this datum uses `Everest 1830 (1937 Adjustment)` or `EPSG 7015` ellipsoid
`da = 860.655`
`df = 0.000028361368`